# guzzle 6 post does not work

Tags: guzzle, guzzle6

I am trying to submit a post with JSON content. I always get this message back:

> "Client
>   error: `POST
>   https://sandbox-api-ca.metrc.com//strains/v1/create?licenseNumber=CML17-0000001`
>   resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"Message":"No data was
>   submitted."}"

(All keys and license number are sandbox. I changed keys slightly so auth wont work. )

here is my code

```
 public function metrc()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $url = 'https://sandbox-api-ca.metrc.com//strains/v1/create?licenseNumber=CML17-0000001';

        $request = $client->post($url, [
            'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
            'json' => ['name' => "Spring Hill Kush"],
            'auth' => ['kH-qsC1oJPzQnyWMrXjw0EQh812jHOX52ALfUIm-dyE3Wy0h', 'fusVbe4Yv6W1DGNuxKNhByXU6RO6jSUPcbRCoRDD98VNXc4D'],

        ]);
    }
```

Comment: [API Docs](https://api-co.metrc.com/Documentation/#Strains.post_strains_v1_create) state you need to submit an array of objects with a `Name` key. You are just sending one of those objects right now. Maybe adding that extra array makes your request valid: `'json' => [['name' => "Spring Hill Kush"]]`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, it should works as expected. Seems that the issue is on the server side. Maybe the format of the POST request is not correct?

BTW, `'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']` is unnecessary, Guzzle sets the header by itself automatically when you use `json` option.